# Xcode plist saving on simulator but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I am writing a program that is saving a workout to a plist in the sandbox. It saves after a button press and a name is in a textview. After it saves it, it adds the workout to a tableview The implementation works great in the simulator, but not in  on the actual iPhone. Any suggestions? (Also, this is my first post, so please bear with me. Thanks)

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
    NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFileName];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    if ([saveNameTextView.text length] == 0) {  //name is not added to the textview for saving
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops =(" message:@"You need to enter a name for the workout" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK, I'll add a name" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }else { //name is added for saving in the textview
        NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
        NSMutableDictionary *savedWorkout = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        if ([savedWorkout objectForKey:saveNameTextView.text]) { //if the name already exists, alert the user
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops =(" message:@"Name is already taken, please choose another" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }else{  //save the workout
            [savedWorkout setObject:self.saveDetails forKey:saveNameTextView.text];
            [savedWorkout writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
            NSString* saveConfirm = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ has been saved",saveNameTextView.text];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save Complete" message:saveConfirm delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }//end if
    }//end if
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that plist already exists when you call `initWithContentOfFile:`? Check with `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]`.

Comment: i thought when you write to the file, if it doesnt exist, it creates it. And if not, how do I create it in the Documents folder?

Comment: It's true, when you call write, it will be created if needed. But in your code you init a dictionary from a file that doesn't exist. This will result in savedWorkout being nil. Then you send it a message (`objectForKey:`) which will return `nil`, because sending a message to `nil` will always return `nil`. So in that case the else block is executed. You send a `writeToFile:` message to `nil` which will simply do nothing. You should check if `initWithContentsOfFile:` actually returns something and initialize your `NSMutableDictionary`` from scratch if needed.

Comment: That is exactly what was wrong. I set up an if statement checking the contents of the file, and everything works now. Thank you sooooo much, you were a huge help =D